# What is $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{1 - \cos x}{x+y}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to understand this multivariate limit.

WolframAlpha says $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{1 - \cos x}{x+y} = 0$

But what if I take a curve $y = -x$, then the limit doesn't exist, right? Wouldn't this make the limit inexistent?

I tried to prove using sandwich theorem and definition, but didn't get anything good.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function $f(x, y) = \frac{1-\cos(x)}{x+y}$ is not defined if $x+y = 0$. But even if restricted to the domain
$$
D = \{ (x, y) \in \Bbb R^2 \mid x+y \ne 0 \} \,
$$
the limit does not exist: For $a \ne 0$ we have $(x, ax^2-x) \to (0, 0)$ for $x \to 0$, but the limit
$$
 \lim_{x \to 0} f(x, ax^2-x) =  \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{ax^2} = \frac{1}{2a}
$$
depends on $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Method $-1.$

$$\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{1 - \cos x}{x+y} &=2\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}{x+y}\end{align}$$

Let  $y(x):=r\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)-x$, as $x\to 0$ and $r\in\mathbb R\setminus \left\{0\right\}$ then we get

> $$\begin{align}2\lim_{(x,y(x)) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin^2(\frac x2)}{x+y}=2\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}{r\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}=\frac 2r\end{align}$$

This means, the limit doesn't exist. Because, the evaluation of the original limit is dependent on $r.$

---

Method $-2.$

$$\begin{align}\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{1 - \cos x}{x+y} &=2\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}{x+y}\end{align}$$

Let  $y(x):=\left(\frac x2\right)^3-x$ as $x\to 0$, then we have

> $$\begin{align}2\lim_{(x,y(x)) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}{x+y}=2\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}{\left(\frac x2\right)^3}\longrightarrow \text{limit does not exist.}\end{align}$$

Because,

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}{\left(\frac x2\right)^3}=+\infty\\ \lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)}{\left(\frac x2\right)^3}=-\infty\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you went from $\lim \dfrac{1 - \cos(x+y)\cos y - \sin(x+y)\sin x}{x+y}$ to $\lim \dfrac{1 - \cos(x+y)}{x+y}$?

Comment: @user1618 Of course. $$\sin x=\sin(x+y)=0, \cos y=1$$ as $(x,y )\to (0,0)$.

Comment: There is an error in the second line, $\sin(x)$ should be $\sin(y)$.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you very much.  Actually I just tested in WA now.  Although it is stated that there is no limit in half a second before the answer is "limit doesn't exist" but, 2 seconds later the limit is said to exist.  I don't understand what it's like.  Is WA contradicting itself?

Comment: @MartinR but, $\sin (x+y)=\sin y=0$ is still valid, isn't it?(I'm just commenting to learn.  Needless to say I'm not an expert $\ddot\smile$)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you for point. Now, everthing is clear.

Comment: @MartinR....can we write, $\frac{\sin (x+y)}{x+y}×\sin y\to 0$, if not..can you explain, why? (if you want to explain,of course). Thanks.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong, I have deleted it. But there is an error in the transition from line #2 to line #3. Note that $\cos(y)$ is not a common factor of the first two terms in the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\lim\limits_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x + y} &= 
\left|
\begin{array}{c}
\text{changing the variables:} \\
x = r\cos(\theta) \\
y = r\sin(\theta) \\
(r \in (0, +\infty), \text{ }\theta \in [0, 2\pi]) \\
\Downarrow \\
(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0) \Leftrightarrow r \rightarrow 0
\end{array}
\right| = 
\lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{1-\cos\left(r\cos(\theta)\right)}{r(\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta))} = \\
=\lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{2\sin^2\left(\frac{r}{2}\cos(\theta)\right)}{r\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)} &= 
\left|
\begin{array}{c}
\sin^2\left(\frac{r}{2}\cos(\theta)\right) \underset{r \rightarrow 0}{\sim} \frac{r^2}{4}\cos^2(\theta)
\end{array}
\right| = 
\lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{r^2}{2}\cos^2(\theta)}{r\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)} = \\
\frac{\cos^2(\theta)}{2\sqrt{2}\sin\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)}\lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0}r = 0, \forall \theta\text{ }\left(\theta \ne \frac{3\pi}{4}\right).
\end{aligned}
$$

So the limit equals to zero for all $\theta$ except $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Now, let us check the case when $\theta \rightarrow \pm\frac{3\pi}{4} \Leftrightarrow y \rightarrow -x$.

In this case,

$$
\lim\limits_{\theta \rightarrow \frac{3\pi}{4}}\lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0}\left(\cdot \right) = 0 \ne \pm\infty = \lim\limits_{r \rightarrow 0}\lim\limits_{\theta \rightarrow \pm\frac{3\pi}{4}}\left(\cdot \right)
$$

This means that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Your very first equals sign is incorrect (if $\lim_{r \to 0}$ means that $\theta$ is held constant). In fact, if you follow the chain of equalities, you're writing that the limit in question equals zero, and then in the next paragraph you say that it doesn't exist.

Comment: I have made some changes concluding that the limit doesn't exist. What is wrong with the very equals sign?

Comment: You're writing “[the two-variable limit to be investigated] = ... = ... = 0”, but it's not true that that limit is zero. Letting $r \to 0$ with fixed $\theta$ is not the same as letting $(x,y) \to (0,0)$.

Comment: This is just one way of approaching (0, 0). I want to show that the limit value depends on the direction of approaching (0, 0) point, which means that the limit doesn't exist. I could parameterized it in another way: $x = t, y = t^2$ Then, $\lim\limits_{(x, y) \rightarrow (0, 0)}(\cdot) = \lim\limits_{t \rightarrow 0}(\cdot)$. Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The left-hand side means the actual two-variable limit, which doesn't exist in this case, so it's indeed wrong to say that it's equal to a one-variable limit that does exist. And what if your two investigations give different results? Then you're first saying $A=B$ and then $A=C$, where $B \neq C$, so you're contradicting yourself (and actually both equalities are false).

Comment: By the way, $\lim_{\theta \to 3\pi/4} (\cdot) = +\infty$ isn't correct either, that's only if you approach $3\pi/4$ from below. If you approach it from above, you get $-\infty$ instead.

Comment: I don't see any issue here. The theory says that if the limit exists it doesn't depend on a path of approaching a limit point ($(0 ,0)$ in our case). In my solution, I show that the limit existence depends on a selected path. If I fix an angle $\theta$ and move to the origin along the corresponding line, it is equivalent that $r\rightarrow 0$. In this case, the limit exists for all $\theta$ except $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}$.However, If I approach the line $\theta=\frac{3\pi}{4}$ first ($\theta \rightarrow \pm\frac{3\pi}{4}$)and then move to the origin ($r \rightarrow 0$), the limit doesn't exist

Comment: So we can conclude that the limit value depends on a path of approaching the limit point, which proves that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: It's not the method itself that I'm opposing, it's the way that it's written. If $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist, it's **not** correct to write that it's equal to zero, which is what you're writing (since you're using the **equals** sign).